# How to add ImageView viewPager in ListFragment in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` inside `ListView` in android screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Menu"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="08/01    MidTown"
    android:textColor="#21252D"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

## My ListFragment class

This class is calling the `ArrayAdapter` to load the data into above `Textview`.

```
public class FoodTabFragment extends ListFragment {
  @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getListView().setDivider(null);
    final AppDelegate contextScope = (AppDelegate) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    FoodListAdapter adapt = new FoodListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.layout_listing_food, contextScope.foodList);
    setListAdapter(adapt);
}
}
```

## FoodListAdapter

```
public class FoodListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Food> {
private Context context;
private List<Food> foodList;

public FoodListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Food> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.roomList = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listing_food, parent, false);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

## SlidingImageAdapter

```
public class SlidingImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


private ArrayList<Integer> IMAGES;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;


public SlidingImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> IMAGES) {
    this.context = context;
    this.IMAGES=IMAGES;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return IMAGES.size();
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
    View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.framelayout_listing_image_slider, view, false);
    assert imageLayout != null;
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setImageResource(IMAGES.get(position));
    view.addView(imageLayout, 0);
    return imageLayout;
}
```

## Question

How can I merge `slidingImageAdapter` int `FoodListAdapter`. So that I can add `viewpager` in `Listview` in `layout` class?

Answer (score 0):

In general I would suggest you to move to [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

Below you can find simple solution for your current implementation.

Changes for `FoodListAdapter`:

Change list of food to map, where Food is id and related SlidingImageAdapter is value.

```
private Map<Food, SlidingImageAdapter> foodMap;
```

This will avoid recreating of adapter every getView call.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listing_food, parent, false);
    }
    Food food = getItem(position);
    SlidingImageAdapter adapter; 
    // adapter creation or reuse
    if (foodMap.contains(food)) {
        adapter = foodMap.get(food);
    } else {
        adapter = new SlidingImageAdapter(...);
        foodMap.put(food, adapter);
    }
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.pager).setAdapter(adapter); 
    return convertView;
}
```

P.S. do not forget to override `hashCode()` and `equals(Object o)` in your `Food` entry.

Comment: Alexander thanks for your answer but according to your implementation it is giving me an option on the basis of data in foodmap. What I wan these two adapters

Comment: @AmitPal Sorry, but I don't understand your comment. Could you explain it

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. What i want is to load `viewpager` in each `listview` row. From above `layout` file , `ListFrgment` and `FoodListAdapter` I can see the data in a list view. After that I tried to add viewpager in layout file and now looking for a solution to add `ImageView viewpager` to in each row of `ListItem`.

Comment: @AmitPal, and what is your current problem? It seems, that you code should works as expected

Comment: The problem I am facing is I don't know how to embedd `SlidingImageAdapter` (read from blogs to figure out how to work with viewpager)  methods in `FoodListAdapter`. When you look at the FoodListAdapter class you will only find out that it's just loading the data to `TextView` in layout file. How to load the data in `viewPager` of `Layout` file through `FoodListAdapter` class? Hope this is understandable
Also `SlideImageAdaptr` is extedns with `PagerAdapter` and `FoodListAdapter` is extends with `ArrayAdapter`