# Android viewpager is not loading the Image?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-viewpager

I asked very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816805/how-to-add-imageview-viewpager-in-listfragment-in-android) in the morning but after trying something `viewpager` is not loading the expected images. This is my updated code:

## layout_view_pager_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

## layout_data_listing_food

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Menu"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
  .....
android:focusable="true" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  android:id="@+id/pager"
  ....
  android:layout_alignStart="@id/profilePic" />
```

## FoodListAdapter

```
public class FoodListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Food> {

private Context context;
private List<Food> roomList;
private ViewPager viewPager;
ArrayList<Integer> itemsimg = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public FoodListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Food> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.roomList = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    itemsimg.add(R.drawable.temp_envelope);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_data_listing_food, parent, false);
    }

    ViewPageAdapter slider = new ViewPageAdapter(context,itemsimg);
    ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    vpPager.setAdapter(slider);
   return convertView;
 }
}
```

## ViewPagerAdapter

```
public class ViewPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private ArrayList<Integer> pagerItems;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

public ViewPageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> pagerItems) {
    super();
    this.pagerItems = pagerItems;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    try {
        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_view_pager_item, container, false);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageResource(pagerItems.get(position));
        container.addView(imageLayout, 0);
        return imageLayout;
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
 }

    @Override
public int getCount() {
    return pagerItems.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}
}
```

## Expectation

- List view should have to show `viewpager` data in each row (Right now I hardcoded the `viewpager` data)
- Each row will contain `Viewpager` and `TextView` as we can see in `layout_data_listing_food` `ViewPager ImageView` just after the `TextView`

What I am doing wrong here? When I debug the code there was not Error :(
and data is also passing from one class to another. Any help would be appreciable

## Problem

I can't see the `Image` loading through `Viewpager` but I can see the  `TextView` content in `layout` file

Comment: did you try loading the images with picasso?

Comment: Not yet but I will use picasso to render the Images in viewpager because all image is at remote position but How can I use picasso in Viewpager?

Comment: Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView);

Comment: can you please replace  container.addView(imageLayout, 0); with container.addView(imageLayout), I am sure it will work

Comment: @dex I did but nothing changed

Comment: @RaviGadipudi This will load the Image but how to add with current position in `instantiateItem` method?

Comment: i didn't get your problem. Can you be more specific. Thanks.

Comment: Amit, where are you filling value in pagerItems arraylist ?? this is the problem I can see in your code, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @RaviGadipudi I replace ` imageView.setImageResource(pagerItems.get(position)); ` with `Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.temp_envelope).into(imageView);` but it didn't work

Comment: What exactly isn't working? I mean, you describe what you expect to happen, you don't describe in detail what actually happens and how that's not what you expected.

Comment: @dex You can see `itemsimg.add(R.drawable.temp_envelope);` in `FoodListAdapter .getView` method

Comment: @Christine I just added `problem` section

Comment: guys any thought on this?

Comment: Amit one more thing can you please try this inside getView method of FoodListAdapter , add this line also vpPager.setId(R.id.pager)

Comment: @dex I just did that but still no progress

Comment: can you please share the code if possible via github, wanna play around at my end !!

Comment: Sorry I can't share (illegal issues) it but the above code is fullfill to check out the issue

Comment: Where does the TextView get a textString?

Comment: @Christine It's hardcoded for now!

Comment: @everyone This is not Imageview loading Issue because When I am changing the ImageView to TextView in `layout_view_pager_item` layout file and  displaying text in `instantiateItem ` method using `SetText`. It's still showing nothing to me